# Excel expert , I need to find ocurrences . Formula use LET TEXTJOINT SUBSTITUTE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: ANOTHER EXAMPLE]    data is in A2:K2:

```
=LET(txt, TEXTJOIN("", FALSE, 0, --A2:K2, 0), modTxt, SUBSTITUTE(txt, "0.5", 1), halfDaysAdjust, 0.5*(LEN(txt)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(txt, "00.50", "0000"))), LEN(modTxt)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(modTxt, "10", "0"))-halfDaysAdjust)
```

This is formula that is giving me the 3 first logics I need to add one more logic without messing up the other logics

Example of logics

```
1 0 1 0 1 = 3 ocurrences 
1 1 1 0 1 = 2 ocurrences 
.5 0 .5 .5 0 = 1.5 ocurrences 
1 .5 0 .5 .5 = 3 ocurrences
```

Description:

First logic :1 are not consecutive is count as separate occurrence

2nd logic: 1s that are consecutive is 1 occurrence

3rd logic:.5 are count as a half point always

4th logic and this is the one I need to add:If a .5 is next to a 1 that .5 becomes in 1 occurrence.

---

This the example [image: ocurrences example]............................

Answer (score 1):

```
=LET(txt,TEXTJOIN("",0,0,--A2:H2,0),
     modtxt,SUBSTITUTE(            
            SUBSTITUTE(txt,"10.5","1010"),                     
                           "0.51","101"),
LEN(modtxt)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(modtxt,"10","1"))
+((LEN(modtxt)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(modtxt,"0.5","00")))/2))
```

I first modified the `1` followed by `0.5` to `1010` so it would count both as a whole. Then I counted the occurances of `10` in the modified text.
I added the count of occurances of `0.5` in the modified text and divided that count by 2 so it would add the count as halves.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for you input . the last logic still not working

Comment: Can you show what you get a wrong result for? (Screenshot was added for reference)

Comment: I am trying to paste the screenshot. It wont let me. this is the example i am testing, I copy and paste your formula and give me the 3.5 result. this report is a 28 day report                          .5 1 0 0 .5 0 0 .5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0= should be 4 ocurrences but your formula is giving me 3.5

Comment: =LET(txt,TEXTJOIN("",0,0,Z138:BA138,0),modtxt,SUBSTITUTE(txt,"10.5","1010"),LEN(modtxt)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(modtxt,"10","1"))+((LEN(modtxt)LEN(SUBSTITUTE(modtxt,"0.5","00")))/2))   This is what i paste

Comment: I see the problem. I read that `.5` should be counted as 1 if it followed a `1`, but I now see the rule is if it's next to a `1`

Comment: See edit to also cope with .5 prior to 1